# Bundle products with exp:resso store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Can the bundle have a price that is different than the sum of the products' prices that make up the bundle?

Example:  If I have 12 tracks at $1 each.  Can the bundle product (the album that contains all 12 tracks) cost $10?

Also, do all products in the bundle have to exist and be purchasable on its own?

Example: If the bundle product (the album) has 14 tracks, I want 2 of those tracks to only be part of the bundle.  The other 12 tracks can be purchased on their own, but not those 2 "bundle-only" tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Store can certainly handle *bundled* products but the one gotcha is that each `bundle` will be a product in it's own right so Store (by default) will have no way of keeping track of individual item sales — tracks in this case. You can however easily set a different price for the bundle. Adrian and Justin have given [a good answer on a similar scenario here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/can-expresso-store-sell-bundles-of-products):

> Since products are stored as channel entries, it's really easy to
>   create bundles of product using Playa, or even standard EE
>   relationships.
>
> Remember you can have multiple product channels. For example, with
>   Tracks and Albums, you could create a channel for Tracks (which has a
>   Store product fieldtype associated with it for individual track
>   sales), and another channel for Albums (which also has a product
>   fieldtype, and is related to the individual tracks.
>
> In your case you could also create a product channels for Tickets,
>   Merchandise, and if you want to create some bundles containing
>   everything, one more called Bundles or something similar, which can be
>   related to any other product channel. How you display this on the
>   front end is entirely up to you.
>
> The only downside to this is that it is not possible to keep track of
>   stock levels for bundled products. If you are selling digital products
>   this isn't an issue, and for physical products it really depends on
>   your client's requirements.

Comment: I have been doing additional research and testing.  Fortunately, the store I'm working on doesn't require inventory management.  So, it looks like the best (only) approach is to create separate products for bundling.  That's not really a bundle as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, each *bundle* will be a product in it's own right and will consist of multiple other products in the system but there is no limit to this. If you have 5 products in your *Products* channel that you want to put into a single *bundle* then create the new *bundle* entry (maybe a separate channel?) and use Playa or standard EE relationships to link to those other products in the system. You can then set the price for the bundle as normal and it will be displayed on your front-end as a regular product. It's in every way a bundle.